# org-export with ox-bibtex outside emacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, bibtex

I want to write a Makefile that handles org-export with ox-bibtex, e.g.

```
%.pdf: %.org
        emacs $< --batch -l emacs-load.el -f org-latex-export-to-pdf --kill

%.html: %.org
        emacs $< --batch -l emacs-load.el -f org-html-export-to-html --kill
```

where `emacs-load.el` contains any elisp needed.

And here start my problems:
I so far have

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "./bibtex2html-1.98-linux/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "./elisp")
(require 'org)
(load "ox-bibtex.el")
```

and the [ox-bibtex.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el;hb=HEAD) copied to `elisp`

With the above configuration, I get

```
Symbol's function definition is void: org-element-insert-before
```

If I provide a function definition (i.e. from [org-element.el](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org-element.el)) org-link-types is void, and so on.

Apparently, I am missing something, but as it stands I do not know what to do in order to make ox-bibtex work.

I want the Makefile to be fully portable (i.e. not depend on a custom emacs configuration) for org-version >= 8.0. (But its OK to require some files in the same directory or a subdirectory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the emacs call seems to be the problem. Should be

```
    emacs --batch -l emacs-load.el $< -f org-latex-export-to-pdf --kill
```

Moreover, I needed to invoke the Makefile located in the org lisp directory hat I placed in my load-path.

It work as expected with the above modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reason that's happening is because the org contributed libraries are not in your load-path.  Ensure that directory is in your load path, and it should work.  See [Installation - The Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) if you don't already have it installed.

If you already have it locally something like this should work:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/orgdir/contrib/lisp" t)
```

My preferred method of installing using the emacs package system.  Here's a link to the org package [repository](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

Comment: I've tried using both - package archive and git repro - nothing. Just to make it clear, export works fine from within my custom emacs. But I want to have a makefile non-emacs users can use without the need to do anything in emacs (but of cause request that they have it installed). I understand that I need to provide the necessary package files together with the project (and load them).